# Simulate app update

Tags: ios, testflight

I am aware of this link:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468180/simulating-app-upgrade-in-ios

Here is my scenario:

1. I uploaded the 2.38.0 version in TestFlight.
2. I installed the app via TestFlight app.
3. I put the newer version 3.2.0 in TestFlight.
4. TestFlight signal an update for my app.
5. I updated the app.
6. All app data from 2.38.0 was deleted.

My questions:

1. Is this normal? (to erase all data from the older app when updating from TestFlight)
2. How can I simulate app update?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: No, it's not normal for an update from TestFlight to delete all data in an app. I regularly update apps via TestFlight, and have never experienced having data deleted.

Most likely you either (a) changed the bundle-ID in your app between the two versions, or (b) saved your data in a non-allowed, non-standard location.

Q2: You can simulate an app update by publishing multiple versions in TestFlight and changing between them.

Another method is to install the app on the device, and then open Settings => General => iPhone Storage. Select your app and press "Offload App". This will delete the app, but keep documents and data - exactly as happens during an update. Afterwards tap the app icon on the home screen again to re-install the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The bundle id is the same but I've changed the app group. Could it be because of this?

Comment: Possibly yes - I assume you're sharing data between apps using app groups.

Comment: How did you offload an app from TestFlight? If I install my app from TestFlight, they don't even show in the iPhone Storage section on my device.